# Filtering odd and even frequencies

Tags: fft, filters

I consider a signal of length $N = 2^n$ for some $n$. I want to derive two signal from it, one containing only the odd frequencies and one only the even frequencies. Each of these signals have length $N/2$.

I use this code in MATLAB:

```
n = 3;
N = 2^n;

signal = ifft( rand(1,N) );

for i = 1:length(signal)/2
    sig1(i) = (signal(i) + signal(i+N/2)) ;
    sig2(i) = (signal(i) - signal(i+N/2)) ;
end

stem(0:N-1,  abs(fft(signal)),'k');
hold on
stem(0:2:N-1, abs(fft(sig1)), 'b*');
hold on;
stem(1:2:N-1, abs(fft(sig2)),'rs');
```

What I should get are two signals, each one of length $N/2$. One containing only the even frequencies and the other one only the odd ones. The way I proceed can be seen either as the first step of the butterfly algorithm in the FFT, or, by using a FIR filter approach, by applying two different filters to my original signal.

However, the signal containing the odd frequencies is always off and when I compare the FFTs they do not match. Why? What is the explanation? I am a bit puzzled by this result.

Comment: What do you mean by your last paragraph? Namely with that the odd signal is always "off". Do you mean that it is shifted to the left or right?

Comment: Are you confusing odd/even frequencies and odd/even symmetry? You method looks like it is trying to do odd/even decomposition. The way to get odd/even frequencies is details simply in the answer from msm

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your code as follows

```
n = 3;
N = 2^n;
signal = rand(1,N);

fft_sig = fft(signal);
fft_sig1 = fft_sig(1:2:end);  % even/odd frequencies
fft_sig2 = fft_sig(2:2:end);  

sig1 = ifft(fft_sig1);        % the actual time-domain signals
sig2 = ifft(fft_sig2); 

stem(0:N-1,  abs(fft_sig),'k');
hold on
stem(0:2:N-1, abs(fft_sig1), 'b*');
stem(1:2:N-1, abs(fft_sig2),'rs');
```